# Ionic and angularjs Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of null

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following problem. I have two exactly the same list views, with directives inside (I use angularJS). One of them runs without any issues, however the other one throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of null
at Object.ionic.views.Scroll.ionic.views.View.inherit.initialize.options.getContentWidth (ionic.bundle.js:4081)
at ionic.views.Scroll.ionic.views.View.inherit.resize (ionic.bundle.js:4835)
at ionic.views.Scroll.ionic.views.View.inherit.run (ionic.bundle.js:4147)
at ionic.bundle.js:39888
at ionic.bundle.js:21929
at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:12022)
at ionic.bundle.js:12330ionic.bundle.js:17696 (anonymous function)ionic.bundle.js:14989 $getionic.bundle.js:21932 (anonymous function)ionic.bundle.js:12022 completeOutstandingRequestionic.bundle.js:12330 (anonymous function)
```

My code is pretty long, so I am not posting it yet - if there is need to do so, I will :)

HINT: I've tested the app on my phone, and it seems that I cant scroll on which the error occurs. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. I simply didnt have any div in my ion-scroll. :)